# possible to set position of dropdowns (zurb foundation)?

Tags: zurb-foundation

right now the content of dropdowns is by default to the bottom right.

Is there an option to set it so it goes to the bottom left?

(foundation 5)

Comment: What do you mean by bottom right? Of its callee? Can you provide a demo?

Comment: just need to look here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html dropdown goes down and to the right. I would like down and to the left

Comment: Having the same issue. Found a reasonable solution, by any chance?

Answer (score 6):

The "right" style is being applied through JS. To override this just give `#contentDrop` a style of `#contentDrop{left: -100px !important;}` or whatever value you would like to pull left. You will need to adjust the `.f-dropdown:after{left:XXpx !important;}` and `.f-dropdown:before{left:XXpx !important;}` stylings to bring the little triangle to the right of the dropdown box.

Comment: I successfully moved the triangle with the `.f-dropdown:after` and `.f-dropdown:before`

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack because Zurb-Foundation is still working on a solution to this problem. There is an [github issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4619) related to this. I found a [Hack here](https://github.com/toggl/pipes-ui/commit/26da3824bde23c7633afd8bb534d8692b9a26fca) that helped me solve it.

Using this information here is how to get the alignment correct. Add a class `bottom-align-left` to the content dropdown `div`:

```
<a href="#" data-options="align:bottom" data-dropdown="drop2">Search</a>
<div id="drop2" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown bottom-align-left">
```

Then add this to your CSS or SCSS file.  You will have to play with the number to get it right.

```
.bottom-align-left {
    margin-left: -375px;
}
```

Now the triangle shows up in the wrong place.  To fix this remove the triangle.

- Open `_settings.scss`.
- Find `$f-dropdown-triangle-size` and set it to `0px` i.e.
  `$f-dropdown-triangle-size: 0px;`